# Android Webview: load html with missing <a>-tags

Tags: android

I'm trying to load html-code into an WebView.

```
webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mywebview);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(getWebviewClient());
webView.addJavascriptInterface(getJavascriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.clearCache(true);


protected WebViewClient getWebviewClient() {
    return new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("mailto:"))) {
                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    };
}


<h1>Title</h1>
<ul>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amen www.test.com
</ul>
```

My problem now is that the link is not being detected (i guess due to the missing anchor tag).

Now when trying...

```
Spannable sp = new SpannableString(html);
Linkify.addLinks(sp, Linkify.ALL);
String html2 = Html.toHtml(sp);
```

and loading html2 into the webview, the links get displayed but the all the other tags are not rendered anymore but displayed as text.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where is your code for initializing your `WebView`?

Comment: Where's your code for `getWebviewClient()`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the line `webView.setWebViewClient(getWebviewClient());`? I'm not sure its needed.

Comment: yeah, changes nothing